# how can I split duplicate columns in a pandas dataframe to join it to the original column with a new index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to split duplicate columns in a data frame to join it to the original column with and add its as a new entry with new index

```
input:

    date        a   b   c   a   b   c
0   2017-11-02  1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2017-11-03  1   2   3   4   5   6

expected:

    date          a   b   c
0   2017-11-02    1   2   3
1   2017-11-02    4   5   6
2   2017-11-03    1   2   3
3   2017-11-03    4   5   6
```

I changed the question little bit, in here string values are introduced instead of numerical values

```
so the new input would be:

        date       event keyword sentiment     event  keyword  sentiment event keyword sentiment
0  2017-11-02  government    gsp+         1      new1   kw3            1  new3    rain        -1
1  2017-11-03     dif eve     kw1         1  dif_eve2   kw3            1   NaN     NaN       NaN

expected output:

         date       event keyword sentiment     
0  2017-11-02  government    gsp+         1      
1  2017-11-02  new1          kw3          1
2  2017-11-02  new3          rain        -1
3  2017-11-03  dif eve       kw1          1     
4  2017-11-03  dif eve2      kw3          1  
5  2017-11-03  NaN           NaN        NaN
```

in this situation how can get the expected output?

Comment: Please produce a [mcve] in the question with input and expected result (no images or links).

Comment: I updated the question please refer

Comment: For instance: make 2 new dataframes with columns 1-3 and 4-6, then concatentate those. You might have to search in the pandas documentation on how to do these operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this worked out by using few things from Wen-Ben's answer

```
s = events_df.melt('date')
print(s)
s['Key'] = s.groupby(['variable', 'date']).cumcount()
print(s)
df1 = s.pivot_table(index=['date', 'Key'], columns='variable', values=['value'], aggfunc='first')
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel()
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1.columns = df1.columns.tolist()
print(df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `pivot_table` after create the additional key with `cumcount`

```
s=df.melt('date')
s['Key']=s.groupby(['variable','date']).cumcount()
yourdf=s.pivot_table(index=['date','Key'],columns='variable',values='value')
yourdf
#yourdf.reset_index(level=0,inplace=True)
variable        a  b  c
date       Key         
2017-11-02 0    1  2  3
           1    4  5  6
2017-11-03 0    1  2  3
           1    4  5  6
```

Comment: what if the data are strings instead of numeric data?